# small block grid not centering thumbs properly

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

i have 3 thumbs i want to center in a row. The code is

```
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
      <li><img class="shadow" src="img/thumbs/carWashHome.jpg"></li>
      <li><img   class="shadow" src="img/thumbs/homeCleanHome.jpg"></li>
      <li><img   class="shadow" src="img/thumbs/carpetCleanHome.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

But somehow the thumbs are starting from left and not in center.
can you suggest be how to fix that.
here is the picture
[image: Thumbs]

Here is the link [LINK](http://www.webcheck.co.in/tulisa/)

You can see that the thumbs are floated to left.
how to center them.
thanks.

Comment: `small-block-grid-3` will float left and assign a width of 33.3333% for each `li`. It sets a padding on the elements so they look evenly spaced. Without seeing more of your code it is hard to tell if there is any conflicting styles.

Comment: You mean i should give padding to list items right?

Comment: Can provide a demo or a URL?

Comment: http://www.webcheck.co.in/tulisa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace a line with following

```
<div class="large-12 columns" style="text-align: center;">
```

Key is to add `style="text-align: center;"` and problem will be fixed

Comment: Thanks. It Worked. But Aditya can you please tell me what does this style mean?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the URL.

Just add `text-align:center;` in your `.small-block-grid-3 > li{}`

Please let me know if you have concerns.

**CSS**

```
.small-block-grid-3 > li{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to your image tags:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

It will align image to `center` present in `li` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Might be nice to know to, that foundation also has a CSS class called "text-center" that can be applied to elements as needed :-)

```
<div class="text-center">
content goes here...
</div>
```